# Couldn't find Employee with id when im trying to add the one more time when enter the wrong data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing the problem when I am trying to edit & add the new data. In this controller I am creating the new data of the relatives with `employee_id`, if I want to change the relative when I added the wrongly using this code I can delete but unable to add. When I am adding it is saying could't find the `employee` with id.

Can any one tell where I am wrong?

```
def employee_relations
        if params[:relative]
            @employee = Employee.find(employee_relative_params[:employee_id])
            @employee_relatives = Relative.where(employee_id: @employee.id, relation_type_id: params[:relative][:relation_type_id])
            @employee_relatives = Relative.create!(employee_relative_params.merge!("created_by" => current_user.id)) if ((@employee_relatives.empty? && params[:relative][:relation_type_id] != '3') || ( params[:relative][:relation_type_id] == '3'))
        else
            @employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])
            @employee_relatives = Relative.where(employee_id: params[:employee_id].to_i)
        end
            @relation_types= Masters::RELATION_TYPE
            respond_with(@employee_relatives)
    end
```

for removing the data: this is for deletion it will work perfectly. if
 I pass the `params` here like

```
employee_relative = Relative.find_by_id(params[:employee_relation_id][:employee_id])
```

it is
 throwing the `nil` value

```
def remove_employee_relation
  employee_relative = Relative.find_by_id(params[:employee_relation_id])
  employee_relative.destroy if employee_relative
  @relation_types= Masters::RELATION_TYPE
  respond_with({:msg => "success"}, :location => nil)
end
```

Comment: Can you post the exact error and the `params` that are generated for that action in the question?

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Employee with 'id'=):
  app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:179:in `employee_relations'    when im trying to edit the relative and new one means replacing to new one with onld one

Comment: What are the `params` that are generated for that action?

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "relative"=>{"relation_type_id"=>"3", "relation_name"=>"DADsdsd", "date_of_birth"=>"", "sex"=>"Male", "status"=>"Alive", "employee_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}

Comment: So the `employee_id` has a `nil` value in the `params`. Can you post your form in the question?

Comment: Above parameter im not getting an employee_id it is taking the nill

Comment: excatly it has to come like when im newly creating the employee data by that time i m able to ctreate as well as im getting employee_id also while editing means old-one replacing with new one im not getting data

Comment: Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "relative"=>{"relation_type_id"=>"0", "relation_name"=>"DAD", "date_of_birth"=>"03-02-1970", "sex"=>"Male", "status"=>"Alive", "employee_id"=>"1487"}, "commit"=>"Save"}

Comment: Please edit your question with the form code, don't post here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a value for employee_id.  From your post:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "relative"=>{"relation_type_id"=>"3", "relation_name"=>"DADsdsd", "date_of_birth"=>"", "sex"=>"Male", "status"=>"Alive", "employee_id"=>""}, "commit"=>"Save"}
```

So your employee id is not being set wherever you are setting it(I am assuming in your form).